# Chi square by association on categorical variables

Tags: r, categorical-data, chi-squared-test

I am conducting a review of methods used over years in different locations and forests.
I have a data set that looks like this (this is only a portion, I have 395 rows):

```r
year               country          Region reason.for.study.1 reason.for.study.2           forest           method encoded_method encoded_forest
1  2020              Colombia   South America              niche                 na       Rainforest    method_visual              5              3
2  2015                 Japan            Asia     Climatic chage            Drought       Rainforest    method_visual              5              3
3  2018             Indonesia            Asia           survival                 na       Rainforest       method_net              3              3
4  2018             Indonesia            Asia           survival                 na       Rainforest method_telemetry              4              3
5  2019               Malasia            Asia      Deforestation            farming       Rainforest    method_visual              5              3
6  2017                Brazil   South America            Methods            Surveys       Rainforest    method_visual              5              3
7  2018                Mexico Central America           Abundace                 na Tropical Island     method_visual              5              6
8  2018               Malasia            Asia          Behaviour            Feeding       Rainforest    method_visual              5              3
9  2012             Australia         Oceania           Abundace            Surveys       Rainforest    method_visual              5              3
10 2017             Indonesia            Asia      Deforestation         recovering       Rainforest    method_visual              5              3
11 2002                Brazil   South America      Deforestation          abundance       Rainforest       method_net              3              3
12 2015                  Peru   South America            Methods            Surveys       Rainforest    method_visual              5              3
13 2015                  Peru   South America            Methods            Surveys       Rainforest  method_acoustic              1              3
```

I'd like to test if there is an association between the forest (contains 6 levels, rainforest, tropical island, tropic, farmland, grassland and more than one) and method (also containing 5 levels, method_net, method_visual, method_acoustic, method_telemetry and method_camera).

Using R, I've been trying to compare these two unique variables (forest and method) using chi-square, but not having much success and I'd also like to know what effect other variables have, such as year or country. Doing comparisons one by one seems a very ineffective way and I was wondering if there is a way to do this in a more straightforward way.

Comment: *using chi-square, but not having much success and I'd also like to know what effect other variables have, such as year or country. Doing comparisons one by one seems a very ineffective way and I was wondering if there is a way to do this in a more straightforward way.* --  to me, these questions appear to be more about statistics rather than programming.

Comment: Can you give more detail on what "not having much success" means ... ?

Comment: If your variables were continuous, what would you do?

Comment: How else could you conduct multiple independent, unrelated tests if not one-by-one? I'm not sure if this is a statistics question about building a multivariate model, or a programming question of how to programmatically run all the univariate test without explicitly coding them. Just running a chi-squared test between all pairs of variables is about as straightforward an approach as you can get. Whether it's "effective" will depend on the true underlying associations - it's fine for single-variable effects, but won't find interactions, for example.